# Advanced ePub reader

Tags: php, jquery, epub

I'm trying to build an advanced ePub reader using jQuery and PHP/Zend Framework1.12 (for the epub3.0 format). The reader should contain the following features:

- books should be displayed using pages (2 pages at a time)
- the user should be able to navigate between pages and chapters using a slider
- the user can create highlights and bookmark pages
- the reader must be cross-browser (I don't care much about older versions of IE, but it must work on Safari, Mozilla, Chrome)

My idea is to make some kind of PHP parser that will handle the epub content and pass it on to the Javascript code in a more 'friendly' format, but I haven't worked with epubs before and I'm not sure where to start.

Here are a few questions that I have been struggling with:

1. The first problem I have encountered is how to extract the content from an .ePub archive and render it in a such a way that will allow the paginated view. What PHP library would you recommend for parsing epubs? I have already tested some libraries like [BookGluttonEpub](https://github.com/Vaporbook/BookGluttonEpub) (seems quite old) and [EPUBParser](https://github.com/KitaitiMakoto/PHP-EPUBParser) (difficult to understand since there are no examples and docs). Are there others I missed?
2. Should I clean the html code (like remove invalid tags for example) before passing it to the reader?
3. What do you consider is the best way to display the pages? Should I use CSS and the 'column' property? Or should I make a more advanced script that will split the html content of a chapter into pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First extract the .epub file, its same like your zip file so you can use PHP unzip library and dont need to parse HTML or CSS. You can create your reader using HTML5 canvas and CSS 3 properties.

I think better option is to use HTML5 and CSS3 if you are not thinking IE compatibility.

Comment: I agree that using HTML5 & CSS3 seems a better solution. Not sure if I agree with the first part, that means I would have to use only Javascript code for rendering. In this case, I would have to load all the epub files and calculate the length of each chapter (to use in the navigation slider), which can be slow for large epubs.

Comment: I built the following solution: 1. Used HTML5 & CSS3 for rendering (the reader doesn't work on IE8 & 9); 2. Calculated the progress bar percentages using the file size of each chapter (this is an approximate value since it doesn't take into consideration how much space the images take); 3. Used jQuery for creating highlights/bookmarks. When navigation through them, the highlights are searched in each chapter file using the progress bar percentage (apx. where in the book they are located) and the text that was selected. Bookmarks are created in a similar way, by simulating a click on the page.